# Cannot get a cookie with Selenium java library

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I open up https://www.goodreads.com/ and do

```
Cookie user_cookie=driver.manage().getCookieNamed("UID");
```

I see "user_cookie is null". But I can get a cookie like "locale".
I can't see the Secure mark across the UID cookie in Google Developer Tools.
What's the problem for the driver to retrieve the UID cookie?

```
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 62.0.3202.94, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not there at the time you pull it. Have you tried printing the names of all the cookies it does find?

Comment: JeffC maybe right. Do you wait on loading the page?

Comment: I do wait for the page to load explicitly:
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
And even when I add Thread.sleep(10000); to wait 10 seconds after the driver receives the command to navigate to the page, I still can't retrieve the needed cookie.

Comment: After loading https://www.goodreads.com/ there are 11 cookies from this domain in total. None of these is named "UID".